# Carbon - Get labels for CopySymbolicHotkeys?

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

[This answer about `CopySymbolicKeys()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10201317/2708274) gets you the keyboard combinations for System Shortcuts in OS X, but is there any way to get at the labels associated with those combinations?

For example, I can get `⌥⌘D` from `CopySymbolicKeys()` but I want to get "Turn Dock Hiding On/Off", its associated label in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

I'm think it's unlikely, but remain hopeful.

Comment: I am trying to achieve similar thing. Maybe it is position (indexed) in always one way and there can be done some mapping?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no API for that, but it is possible to reconstruct what you want. It will need some work from you though.

You can get the names of the symbolic keys here:

- Earlier macOS versions: `System/Library/PreferencePanes/Keyboard.prefPane/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DefaultShortcutsTable.xml`
- macOS 13 Ventura: `/System/Library/ExtensionKit/Extensions/KeyboardSettings.appex/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DefaultShortcutsTable.xml`

You need to parse this `XML` file and then find the corresponding hotkey here:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```

The matching must be done between key `sybmolichotkey` (yes, the key is misspelled like that!) in the aforementioned `XML` file with key called `key` containing the same number in the latter `plist` file.

Example taken from the `DefaultShortcutsTable.xml` file:

```
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>DO_NOT_LOCALIZE: Dashboard and Dock</string>
        <key>ax_description</key>
        <string>DO_NOT_LOCALIZE: Dashboard and Dock shortcuts (AX_DESCRIPTION)</string>
        <key>identifier</key>
        <string>dock</string>
        <key>iconname</key>
        <string>category_dock</string>
        <key>icon-bundle-path</key>
        <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app</string>
        <key>canRestoreDefaults</key>
        <true/>
        <key>elements</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>DO_NOT_LOCALIZE: Turn Dock Hiding On/Off</string>
                <key>key</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>modifier</key>
                <integer>1572864</integer>
                <key>sybmolichotkey</key>  <--- look for this key
                <integer>52</integer>      <--- and its value
                <key>charKey</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>DO_NOT_LOCALIZE: Show Launchpad</string>
                <key>key</key>
                <integer>65535</integer>
                <key>modifier</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>sybmolichotkey</key>  <--- look for this key
                <integer>160</integer>     <--- and its value
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

And then look for the same number in `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`:

```
    <key>52</key>
    <dict>
        <key>enabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>value</key>
        <dict>
            <key>parameters</key>
            <array>
                <integer>65535</integer>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <integer>1572864</integer>
            </array>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>standard</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Major caveat: the latter `plist` is in binary form. To convert it to text, you need to do this in Terminal:

```
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```